# SDL2 textures don't work with pixel format ARGB2101010

Tags: c++, macos, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to use a texture with the `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB2101010` color format but I only get a black texture. The same program works when using the `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARG88888` format.

None of SDL's variables are null. This is my code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0);
    SDL_Renderer *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
    SDL_Texture *tex = SDL_CreateTexture(ren, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB2101010, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);
    
    
    uint32_t* buffer = new uint32_t[bufferWidth * bufferHeight];
                      
    for(int bufferIdx = 0; bufferIdx < bufferWidth * bufferHeight; bufferIdx++) {
        buffer[bufferIdx] = 0xc0ffffff;
    }

    SDL_Event event;
        
    while(running) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                running = false;
        }
    
        SDL_UpdateTexture(tex, nullptr, buffer, bufferWidth * 4);
        SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, nullptr, nullptr);
        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    }
}
```

This is some of my hardware and software:

- AMD Radeon Pro 5500M GPU
- SDL Version 2.0.14
- MacOS 11.1
- C++14
- Compiled with default Xcode 12.3 settings

Comment: I think you should try SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED instead of SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE. I would select direct3d or opengl hints if possible.

Comment: @jpaguerre I tried the renderer typ, but how do I enable opengl hints?

Comment: SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl"); before creating the window

Comment: @jpaguerre sadly this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: what color are you trying to show? It would not be the same one as you get with 8888, since of course the internal representation is different. 2101010 means 2 bits for alpha, and 10 for each color channel

Comment: @jpaguerre I just tried to show ´0xffffffff´ which should be white in any colourspace but I also tried ´0´ and ´0x00ffffff´ to test if the channels where inverted but it always displayed black